# What's differernce betwen scanf("%s"), scanf(" %s") and scanf("%s ")?

Tags: c, scanf

I am confused with this syntax. At first, I thought it was a printing error in the book. But, while programming for quite a long time I came to know that they have different meaning. Still, I'm not able to get clear vision about that syntax.

Likewise, what's difference between:

`gets( str);`
and 
`gets(str);`

Does whitespace matter? If yes, then how?

Comment: Difference? IDK, but there's a similarity: you shouldn't be using any of them (`gets()` included). Use `fgets()` instead. Also, there's **obviously** no difference between `gets( buf)` and `gets(buf)` -- ***don't confuse code with string literals.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When adding a space in the `scanf` format string, you tell `scanf` to read and skip whitespace. It can be usefull to skip newlines in the input for example. Also note that some formats automatically skip whitespace anyway.

See e.g. [here for a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) of the `scanf` family of functions.

---

The difference between

```
gets(str);
```

and

```
gets( str );
```

is none at all. Actual code outside of string literals can be formatted with any amount of whitespace. You could even write the above call as

```
gets
    (
        str
    )
;
```

It would still be the same.

Oh, and the `gets` function is deprecated since long ago, and even removed from the latest C standard. You should use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: s/deprecated/removed/ (`gets` was _removed_ from the C Standard Library in C11 because it is superlatively awful)

Comment: I have heard something like whitespace before scanf command help flushing memory. How much is it true?

Can you tell something about flushing too?

Comment: @Habi No flushing is involved. But if the input buffer is exhausted during the scanning, new data is read into the buffer of course.

Comment: Joachim, aren't input buffer and memory similar to each other?

and talking about "reading new data into the buffer of course", does it apply on both cases. I mean does it apply to scanf function with whitespace and scanf without whitespace.

Likewise,Does having whitespace before %s and having whitespace after %s make any difference?

Comment: @Habi Well the buffer used is of course in memory, but there's no *explicit* flushing. And the space in the format strings skips whitespace where it is, so if it's before a format code then is skips whitespace before scanning, if the space if after the format then it skips whitespace after the scanning.

Answer (score 2):

> White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including **none**, in the input.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/

In `gets` the space does not mean anything. Its ignored on compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler has many phases and in the first phase lexical analysis,
all unnecessary white spaces are removed this is also unnecessary space which will be removed at that time and so,
there is no difference between `gets(a) and gets( a)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important things to learn about scanf here:

1. All conversion modifiers except %c and %[ ignore whitespace before the scanned item.
2. You can explicitly invoke this behavior of ignoring all whitespace as follows:

   `scanf(" %c", &mychar)`

   `scanf("\n%c", &mychar)`

   `scanf("\t%c", &mychar)`

That is, any whitespace character (including spaces) in your conversion string instructs scanf to ignore any and all whitespace up until the scanned item.

Since all conversion modifiers except %c and %[ do this automatically, the answer to your original question about `scanf("%s")` versus `scanf(" %s")` is that there is no difference.

I would recommend reading all the scanf questions at the C FAQ and writing some test programs to get a better grasp of it all:

http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html